# Can shareholders’ equity be more than total assets?

Tags: stocks, terminology, assets, liabilities

I was just learning about DuPont Identity on investopedia with this [example](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dupontidentity.asp):

```
#DuPont Identity Example Calculation
Assume a company reports the following financial data for two years:

Year one net income = $180,000
Year one revenues = $300,000
Year one total assets = $500,000
Year one shareholder equity = $900,000

Year two net income = $170,000
Year two revenues = $327,000
Year two total assets = $545,000
Year two shareholder equity = $980,000

Using the DuPont identity, the ROE for each year is:

ROE year one = ($180,000 / $300,000) x ($300,000 / $500,000) x ($500,000 / $900,000) = 20%
ROE year two = ($170,000 / $327,000) x ($327,000 / $545,000) x ($545,000 / $980,000) = 17%

With a slight amount of rounding, the above two ROE calculations break down to:

ROE year one = 60% x 60% x 56% = 20%
ROE year two = 52% x 60% x 56% = 17%
```

But I just [read that](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/shareholdersequity.asp),

**Shareholders’ equity = total assets − total liabilities**
​

So the total liabilities should be a negative value in order to get a greater shareholder equity than the total assets.

I am clearly missing some pieces of the puzzle, but I don't know what.

Comment: A negative liability (like a prepaid liability) would be an asset, no?

Comment: Technically yes, but still should be stated as a positive value in accounting, shouldn't be?

Comment: Oh, yes.  "Prepaid utilities" or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the example is incorrect.   Good catch.